# How can I forward certain emails based on header information with Postfix?

Tags: postfix, redirect, mail-forwarding

We receive service requests via a particular email.  The request is then forwarded to other addresses, using an entry in *virtual_alias_maps*.  Upon seeing the word "EMERGENCY" in the subject line of a request to this email, I would also like to forward this to another address (an alias of our administrator's SMS email addresses).

I think I can accomplish this with *header checks* and the REDIRECT command.  However, REDIRECT only sends it to the redirected address, not the forwarded addresses.  In the case of "EMERGENCY" I would like it to go to the redirect address and the original forwarded addresses.

I am fairly new to Postfix and I feel like I am missing something here.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm more of a QMAIL sort of guy but this sounds like a job for procmail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, Postfix won't act upon the message *contents* without outside help, it acts on the *envelope* information. Things like the `Subject` belong to the message contents.

I think the easiest way to manage such things is to include an extra email address to the ones already receiving, which is actually a forward to a script (you can do that in `/etc/aliases` by prefixing the destination with a pipe symbol, read `man aliases`) that performs your requested tests on its standard input (the message contents) and acts accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

this can be done by:

a.) add a new smtpd listener to master.cf setting the -o always_bcc option to the address you want and have this new smtpd process listen on some port like 10027;  create a second smtpd listener on 10028 - set options in this smtpd instance for delivery to final destinations as you would a standard smtpd instance.  See http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_PROXY_README.html for more info

b.) in your header check, use the filter action and send any matching subject to filter inet:127.0.0.1:10027

alternately, you could install an additional postfix instance and route messages to that via step a as well ... many different ways to do this.